# sequentially loop non-sequential query results from database

Tags: c#, .net

I need to create a wizard with questions and answers.
So i have a table with  answers and when I load the wizard i want to have first answer as
label  and near a dropdown with posible answers  and next button.When I click next button  selected answer and question id  is saved in database and second question is loaded and continue like this until all questions are finished.

Lately I worked only in coldfusion and there i can loop over query and its simple but in C# i dont know how to do this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{ 
using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd.CommandType =   CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = "dbo.GetFurnizori";                                           


                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_id",i);
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                DataTable dat = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
                sqlDA.SelectCommand = sqlCmd;
                dat.Fill(dataSet1, "questions");
                label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataSet1, "question");
            }                
          }
```

The problem is that i canot go with i increment by 1 because id are not always 1,2,3,4 maybe they are 5,9 ,11

Comment: If you don't know C#, go and learn it. We're not here to teach you. You attend school for that... This is a Q&A site, not a preschool where you get everything on a silver plate.

Comment: Ask a *specific* question about a *specific* practical programming problem: a general task is not a specific problem in this sense; it's just some steps [for you] to carryout. Make sure to post the relevant code.

Comment: I think there is more of a question here than is being given credit for.  The problem lies in articulation.  jonny is asking how to sequentialize something that is not sequential.  That would be more evident if the question were clearer, but we shouldn't act as if there is a lack of effort.

Answer (score 1):

If you are querying against SQL Server, add a `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` to your query within the stored procedure (you'll have to read up on it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).  This will give you a sequential number (1,2,3,etc.) for each of the rows returned.  That might help, since you wouldn't have to rely on `id`.  You can pass `i` (and continue with `i++`) into the proc and have the proc find the row in query whose `ROW_NUMBER()`, not whose `id` is `i`.